# Can one use list comprehension derivatives in its methods?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Consider the following code:

```
a = [... for i in input]
i = a.index(f(a))
```

I'm wondering whether I could be able to do an one-liner. Obvious try is:

```
i = [... for i in input].index(f([... for i in input]))
```

But this solution requires list to be generated twice.
Not-so-obvious try is:

```
i = [ a.index(f(a)) for a in [[... for i in input],] ]
```

Which does the trick, but makes code really weird.

This leads me to idea that probably there is possibility to somehow use list, generated by list comprehension, in its own method call. Something like (both not working, obviously):

```
i = [... for i in input].index(f(_))
# or
i = [... for i in input].index(f(self))
```

Can it be done?

Comment: Why do you want to kill readability? :)

Comment: What does f() do? Do you simply want to get the index of a certain list element?

Comment: You could create a lambda and immediately call it with your comprehension: `i = (lambda x: x.index(f(x))([... for i in input])` But this is heresy. Also, don't name an iterable input, that masks the built-in input function.

Comment: [Kasra's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30126780/2653390) shows the best practice for this kind of thing.

Comment: IIRC the canonical quick and merge sorts in Python both use duplicated list comprehensions. Keep in mind that a constant factor doesn't significantly increase algorithmic complexity. That said, some programming languages (like Haskell), don't have to re-evaluate identical functions guaranteed to give the same result. Either way, it's not necessary to jump through hoops to avoid a second loop.

Comment: @ODiogoSilva , for this particular task - yes, but my interest is more like is there any builtin variable like "_", that could allow me access results not of previous expression, but of previous calculated term within expression (while I was thinking of stack used in python bytecode I guessed that there could be one)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini, actually I think that could such variable exist it would make code much more readable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that avoids repeating the list-comprehension is to create an anonymous function and calling it directly (untested):

```
i = (lambda a: a.index(f(a)))([... for i in input])
```

This is still a bit ugly, though. Your first example that used the temporary variable `a` is much clearer. Writing one-liners as an exercise is fun, but it is usually not the best way for writing maintainable code.

Answer (score 6):

As you are doing a recursion task, based on what your function does you can mix your function with a list comprehension or a generator expression.

for example consider the following code :

```
>>> f=lambda x:next(i for i in x if i.startswith('a'))
>>> 
>>> a=['df','sr','t','aaf','ar','trf']
>>> a.index(f(a))
3
```

You can mix like following using `enumerate` :

```
>>> next(i for i,j in enumerate(a) if j.startswith('a'))
3
```

So its all based on your **function** that how you can put its structure within a list comprehension or a generator expression,and then apply some changes on it and use python tools based on your needs (in this case we used `enumerate`).

Comment: as far as I can see - your solution works only for simple indexing tasks; however it is not applicable generally. The simplest example I can think of is if f=min(mylist), so we could retrieve index of minimal element from generator. It does not seem obvious to me, how you solution could be used for such case. And also, as I mentioned in comment higher - my interest is whether there is any builtin variable like "_", only that one could allow me access results not of previous expression, but of previous calculated term within expression.